# Подлежашее сказуемое

Tags: сказуемые, подлежащее

Человек любящий и умеющий читать по настоящему счастлив. Вопрос: 1)Чем выражено подлежащее? 2)Что подлежашее и сказуемое?

Comment: Подлежашие ваши — смешные: каждое второе шепелявит.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, пунктуация в предложении неправильная. Правильная запись:

> Человек, любящий и умеющий читать, по-настоящему счастлив.

Подлежащее здесь выражено существительным ***человек***, а сказуемое — прилагательным в краткой форме ***счастлив***.